# upgrade IWS 9.4 from 9.2 and DB2

Tags: workload-scheduler

We have DB2 10.1 ese which came with TWS 9.2 package. As per the IWS 9.4 supported software prerequisite, IWS 9.4 only supports the DB2 AWSE or WSE as below. Are you sure the IWS 9.4  will support DB2 10.1?  Can we keep the current version of DB2 for future IWS version?

So please confirm us the DB2 supported version of IWS 9.4 FP02. we need concrete information about the supported software prerequisite before going for the upgrade.

I need your advice on DB2 version. IBM L3 team suggest DB2 AWSE 11.1  and you suggest DB2 WSE 10.5. which one is best for IWS 9.4? I just go through the functionality comparison of both version and I could not conclude which one is suitable for us.

Comment: Did you really just post your client's email here?

Answer (score 0):

the customer can do in 2 different manner:

1) Install a TWS 9.4 bkmdm and attach it to DB2 10.1 ese (that is the one for TWS 9.2) then after the parallel upgrade has been completed migrate the db2 10.1 ese to db2 11.1 ese and then convert the license to db2 10.5 WSE in that way
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0061044.htm

2) Customer can install in a separate machine the DB2 10.5 wse , perform db2backup and db2 restore into db2 10.5 wse , then attach the TWS 9.2 mdm to db2 10.5 ese and then perform the parallel upgrade.

thanks